# Datagrid, hide zero values with StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I know it's a question already posted, and believe me, I tried different way to format the string without success. I am with a datagrid, this is my pieces of code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
    <Binding Path="Valmax" StringFormat="#">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
           <local:takedownvalidation Min="0" Max="63"/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
```

nothing change if I use different format like "##;##;##" or similar.
Please note "Valmax" it's a string whose format could be as integer type "12" or char type "N", but with "0" I would like to show nothing on datagrid, thanks for any hints.

Comment: Why don't you use a binding converter?

Comment: @Clemens, yes I will do if this easier solution does not fit, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see that, if 'Valmax' is of type byte (my case, but probably with integral), stringFormat works fine, when you set cell to 0, on loose focus, it will clear as aspected. Question remain open if 'Valmax' is string type.